# ModelSim-Altera error

Tags: linux, licensing, modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

I'm using Ubuntu Linux 14.04 LTS with Altera Quartus 15.0 web-edition and I'm having a hard time simulate my design due to licensing errors. I'm designing an LCD_driver for the [VEEK-MT](http://goo.gl/QFxON0)'s LCD touch screen by terasic with the [Cyclone IV EP4CE115](http://goo.gl/mKhYzU) by Altera.

Honestly, I don't have much of experience with simulation software like **ModelSim-Altera** but I do know how to use **.vwf** files and simulate with them, I know as well how to use signaltap logic analyzer. After creating the **usinversity program .vwf** files, I compile the project, I press ***run functional simulation*** and I get a window with the following content:

> Determining the location of the ModelSim executable...
>
> Using: /home/bdoronnb/Downloads/Quartus/15.0/ModelSim/modelsim_ase/bin
>
> To specify a ModelSim executable directory, select: Tools -> Options
>   -> EDA Tool Options Note: if both ModelSim-Altera and ModelSim executables are available, ModelSim-Altera will be used.
>
> **** Generating the ModelSim Testbench ****
>
> quartus_eda --gen_testbench --check_outputs=on --tool=modelsim_oem
>   --format=verilog --write_settings_files=off test5 -c test5 --vector_source="/path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/test5.vwf"
>   --testbench_file="/path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/simulation/qsim/test5.vwf.vt"
>
> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 762: _dl_close: Assertion
>   `map->l_init_called' failed! Info:
>   *******************************************************************Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit EDA Netlist Writer    Info: Version 15.0.0
>   Build 145 04/22/2015 SJ Web Edition    Info: Copyright (C) 1991-2015
>   Altera Corporation. All rights reserved.    Info: Your use of Altera
>   Corporation's design tools, logic functions     Info: and other
>   software and tools, and its AMPP partner logic     Info: functions,
>   and any output files from any of the foregoing     Info: (including
>   device programming or simulation files), and any     Info: associated
>   documentation or information are expressly subject     Info: to the
>   terms and conditions of the Altera Program License     Info:
>   Subscription Agreement, the Altera Quartus II License Agreement,
>   Info: the Altera MegaCore Function License Agreement, or other
>   Info: applicable license agreement, including, without limitation,
>   Info: that your use is for the sole purpose of programming logic
>   Info: devices manufactured by Altera and sold by Altera or its
>   Info: authorized distributors.  Please refer to the applicable
>   Info: agreement for further details.    Info: Processing started: Sun
>   Aug  9 22:18:46 2015Info: Command: quartus_eda --gen_testbench
>   --check_outputs=on --tool=modelsim_oem --format=verilog --write_settings_files=off test5 -c test5 --vector_source=/path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/test5.vwf
>   --testbench_file=/path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/simulation/qsim/test5.vwf.vtWarning
>   (201007): Can't find port "h_counter" in designWarning (201007): Can't
>   find port "h_counter[10]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[9]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[8]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[7]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[6]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[5]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[4]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[3]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[2]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[1]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port
>   "h_counter[0]" in designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter"
>   in designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[9]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[8]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[7]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[6]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[5]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[4]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[3]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[2]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[1]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "v_counter[0]" in
>   designWarning (201007): Can't find port "HSD_s" in designWarning
>   (201007): Can't find port "VSD_s" in designInfo (201000): Generated
>   Verilog Test Bench File
>   /path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/simulation/qsim/test5.vwf.vt
>   for simulationInfo: Quartus II 64-Bit EDA Netlist Writer was
>   successful. 0 errors, 25 warnings    Info: Peak virtual memory: 1088
>   megabytes    Info: Processing ended: Sun Aug  9 22:18:47 2015    Info:
>   Elapsed time: 00:00:01    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors):
>   00:00:01 Completed successfully.
>
> Completed successfully.
>
> **** Generating the functional simulation netlist ****
>
> quartus_eda --write_settings_files=off --functional=on
>   --flatten_buses=off --simulation --tool=modelsim_oem --format=verilog --output_directory="/path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/simulation/qsim/"
>   test5 -c test5
>
> Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-close.c: 762: _dl_close: Assertion
>   `map->l_init_called' failed! Info:
>   *******************************************************************Info: Running Quartus II 64-Bit EDA Netlist Writer    Info: Version 15.0.0
>   Build 145 04/22/2015 SJ Web Edition    Info: Copyright (C) 1991-2015
>   Altera Corporation. All rights reserved.    Info: Your use of Altera
>   Corporation's design tools, logic functions     Info: and other
>   software and tools, and its AMPP partner logic     Info: functions,
>   and any output files from any of the foregoing     Info: (including
>   device programming or simulation files), and any     Info: associated
>   documentation or information are expressly subject     Info: to the
>   terms and conditions of the Altera Program License     Info:
>   Subscription Agreement, the Altera Quartus II License Agreement,
>   Info: the Altera MegaCore Function License Agreement, or other
>   Info: applicable license agreement, including, without limitation,
>   Info: that your use is for the sole purpose of programming logic
>   Info: devices manufactured by Altera and sold by Altera or its
>   Info: authorized distributors.  Please refer to the applicable
>   Info: agreement for further details.    Info: Processing started: Sun
>   Aug  9 22:18:53 2015Info: Command: quartus_eda
>   --write_settings_files=off --functional=on --flatten_buses=off --simulation=on --tool=modelsim_oem --format=verilog --output_directory=/path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/simulation/qsim/
>   test5 -c test5Info (204019): Generated file test5.vo in folder
>   "/path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/simulation/qsim//"
>   for EDA simulation toolInfo: Quartus II 64-Bit EDA Netlist Writer was
>   successful. 0 errors, 0 warnings    Info: Peak virtual memory: 1093
>   megabytes    Info: Processing ended: Sun Aug  9 22:18:55 2015    Info:
>   Elapsed time: 00:00:02    Info: Total CPU time (on all processors):
>   00:00:01 Completed successfully.
>
> **** Generating the ModelSim .do script ****
>
> /path/to/Altera/projects/test/5/simulation/qsim/test5.do
>   generated.
>
> Completed successfully.
>
> **** Running the ModelSim simulation ****
>
> /home/bdoronnb/Downloads/Quartus/15.0/ModelSim/modelsim_ase/bin/vsim
>   -c -do test5.do
>
> /home/bdoronnb/Downloads/Quartus/15.0/ModelSim/modelsim_ase/bin/../linux/vish:
>   error while loading shared libraries: libXft.so.2: cannot open shared
>   object file: No such file or directory Error.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: 32b or 64b Linux distribution? Notice that the 32-bit library files are required to run the ModelSim software on Linux 64-bit platforms.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Eureka! I've googled the following text: `error while loading shared libraries: libXft.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Error.` I've found out (thanks to [Qiu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572285/qiu) as well) that I need to install 32bit packages for my 64bit OS that the ModelSim-Altera software uses. Here are is the proper command to enter to the Ubuntu terminal:

`sudo apt-get install libxft2 libxft2:i386 lib32ncurses5`

And problem solved!

Comment: On Ubuntu 14.10 getting libxft2:i386 to install is an endless chain of unmet dependencies, won't install nonsense.. Works fine on Ubuntu 14.04 though..

Comment: @badkya 18.04 doesn't have this problem

Answer (score 0):

Replace lib32ncurses5 with lib32ncurses6. I have corrected the dependency name, the old aren't more available