# Install Qt on Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

Need to build simple GUI application. For this reason I decided to install Qt on my Ubuntu 16. I have downloaded open source Qt edition [from theirs site](https://www.qt.io/download-qt-installer?hsCtaTracking=9f6a2170-a938-42df-a8e2-a9f0b1d6cdce%7C6cb0de4f-9bb5-4778-ab02-bfb62735f3e5). Got error while run:

```
g@ubuntu:~/Downloads$ ./qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.5-2-online.run 
./qt-unified-linux-x86-2.0.5-2-online.run: error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

How to fix that?

Comment: Why not just install it from the repo, using `apt-get`?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install qt`
brings `E: Unable to locate package qt`

Comment: Are you running that under graphical desktop?

Comment: Try `apt-cache search qt` first and then pick the according packages.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Before Debian 11 / Ubuntu 20.10, the ubuntu package name was `qt5-default`.

This package was deprecated and now you should install `qtbase5-dev`, or one of the individual Qt modules if you just want the runtime:

- libqt5concurrent5
- libqt5core5a
- libqt5dbus5
- libqt5gui5
- libqt5network5
- libqt5printsupport5
- libqt5sql5
- libqt5test5
- libqt5widgets5
- libqt5xml5

The corresponding Qt6 package is `qt6-base-dev` (note the extra -).

Comment: Installing the `qtcreator` package will also give you the IDE.

Comment: If for some reason you need the lower Qt 4 version, `qt4-default` is also available.

Comment: this package no longer exists!

Answer (score 130):

**Install Qt**

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential

sudo apt-get install qtcreator

sudo apt-get install qt5-default
```

Install documentation and examples
If Qt Creator is installed thanks to the Ubuntu Sofware Center or thanks to the synaptic package manager, documentation for Qt Creator is not installed. Hitting the F1 key will show you the following message : "No documentation available". This can easily be solved by installing the Qt documentation:

```
sudo apt-get install qt5-doc

sudo apt-get install qt5-doc-html qtbase5-doc-html

sudo apt-get install qtbase5-examples
```

Restart Qt Creator to make the documentation available.

**Error while loading shared libraries**

**Problem:**

radiusd: error while loading shared libraries:
libfreeradius-radius-2.1.10.so:
cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

**Reason:**

Actually, the libraries have been installed in a place where dynamic linker cannot find it.

**Solution:**

While this is not a guarantee but using the following command may help you solve the “cannot open shared object file” error:

```
sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v
```

http://www.lucidarme.me/how-install-documentation-for-qt-creator/

https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2199929

https://itsfoss.com/error-while-loading-shared-libraries/

[ModelSim-Altera error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908525/modelsim-altera-error/)

Comment: (Ubuntu 20.04): installing qtcreator before qt5-default (qt5-qmake) prevented qtcreator from automatically detecting qmake. This had to be manually added via; 1)
`qtcreator - tools - options - Qt Versions - Manual - Add - qmake location: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt5/bin/qmake`, 2)
`qtcreator - tools - options - Manual - Desktop (default) - Qt version - Qt 5.xx`

Comment: The comment above was spot on! I accidentally installed `qtcreator` before `qt5` and had issues, e.g. the creator wasn't showing the examples (Ubuntu 20.04). Following the steps fixed it.

Comment: Now that Qt 6 is out, it seems best to install "qt5-default" first, then "qtcreator", correct ? (supposing you want Qt 5)

Comment: user2585501 give solution for my case.

Comment: UPDATE: qt5-default no longer exists.  If anyone has a workaround, please tell.  Need to install the libs for runtime only, not dev work.

Comment: user2585501 Thanks for the comment, it got me going well! This should be part of the official answer.

Comment: Tried to install qt5-default and now it returns "Package 'qt5-default' has no installation candidate"

Answer (score 4):

In Ubuntu 18.04 the QtCreator examples and API docs missing,
This is my way to solve this problem, should apply to almost every Ubuntu release.

For QtCreator and Examples and API Docs:

```sh
sudo apt install `apt-cache search 5-examples | grep qt | grep example | awk '{print $1 }' | xargs `

sudo apt install `apt-cache search 5-doc | grep "Qt 5 " | awk '{print $1}' | xargs`

sudo apt-get install build-essential qtcreator qt5-default
```

If something is also missing, then:

```sh
sudo apt install `apt-cache search qt | grep 5- | grep ^qt | awk '{print $1}' | xargs `
```

Hope to be helpful.

Also posted in Ask Ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/450983/ubuntu-14-04-qtcreator-qt5-examples-missing

Answer (score 3):

Also take a look at awesome project `aqtinstall` https://github.com/miurahr/aqtinstall/ (it can install any Qt version on Linux, Mac and Windows machines without any interaction!) and GitHub Action that uses this tool: https://github.com/jurplel/install-qt-action

Answer (score 0):

Download latest from your Qt account next in terminal

```
chmod +x qt-unified-linux-x64-4.6.0-online.run 
./qt-unified-linux-x64-4.6.0-online.run
```