# Packaging QT application to an .AppImage file for Linux

Tags: linux, qt, qt5

I am trying to build and package QGC into a standalone .AppImage file for running on Linux (Ubuntu) systems.

My issue is this: I install Qt Creator with desktop gcc for 5.15.2 as described in the [QGC developer docs](https://dev.qgroundcontrol.com/master/en/getting_started/). On Ubuntu 20 with glibc 2.31 I can use Qt Creator to build QGC. Then I try to package it into an .AppImage with [LinuxDeployQT](https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt). This fails and says I must have glibc <= 2.27.

So I got an installation of Ubuntu 18. This has glibc 2.27 by default. The problem with Ubuntu 18 with glibc is when I install QT Creator with 5.15.2 and try to run QT Creator I get an error saying glibc_2.28 is not found.

If >= 2.28 is required to build with Qt Creator, but <= 2.27 is required to package into an .AppImage how is this usually done? I know there is a way to do it, but I don’t know what it is. [The QGC developer docs](https://dev.qgroundcontrol.com/master/en/getting_started/) specify what is needed to build QGC as well as the versioning and deployment strategy, but not how to bundle the app.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same issue, and was hitting my head to the walls:
No way to install Qt from the official installer on Ubuntu 18.04. it was also impossible to deploy any Qt app when using Ubuntu 20.04. The ultimate dead end..

Here is the solution i came up today:

1. Back up the files, do fresh Ubuntu 18.04 installation. Your current Qt installation should be cleaned too
2. Install Qt according to John Ragan's answer, from command line:

[Install Qt on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48147356/install-qt-on-ubuntu)

**Do not use Qt Online Installer!** (this is very critical)

3. Follow Daniel Gakwaya's deployment strategy, by using linuxdeployqt:

https://youtu.be/2B--nzfoQ9s

The command: `./linuxdeployqt-continuous-x86_64.AppImage ./AppName/Appname -appimage` gave me a single .AppImage file, which works as a charm on a ubuntu 20.04 virtualbox

you probably won't have issue with linuxdeployqt, since will be using -appimage option. but if you do, have a check at this forum post:

https://github.com/probonopd/linuxdeployqt/issues/402

hope this solves your issues. happy deployments

Comment: I went ahead and did as you suggested here. I got stuck on the build step. After installing qt5-defualt (which is 5.9.5 on Ubuntu 18 repos), I wasn't able to build with Qt Creator. It says "Unsupported Qt version, 5.15 is required". This is probably just specific to the fact that I'm trying to build QGroundControl. I'm sure your answer here would work for other projects. Thank you for your help!