# Quartus simulatoin fails (Error: 199000)

Tags: modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

I am newbie to Quartus. I have tried both versions 17 and 13.1 and faced a similar problem; I couldn't simulate the block-diagram I had designed.
In the old version I got an error saying path to ModelSim is not set correctly, while I wanted to use ModelSim-altera instead, and *-altera's path was set.
The newer version expresses cuter reactions :))

`Error (199000): Run Analysis and Synthesis with top-level entity name "HW1" or run I/O Assignment Analysis before running the EDA Netlist WriterError: Quartus Prime EDA Netlist Writer was unsuccessful. 1 error, 0 warnings`

Answer (score 0):

Before running functional simulation, I tried to click buttons "Start Analysis and Synthesis" and "Start Analysis and Elaboration."
After that, I faced a problem mentioned in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31908525/modelsim-altera-error). And the answer was there. Hurray